# Angular Material: Md-sidenav-right with md-tabs not working in IE

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

**Note:** This problem can only be seen in IE 11 down. IE Edge (including emulation) will not show the issue.

I'm having a crazy problem when I combined md-tabs with md-sidenav. Here is the plunkr:

http://embed.plnkr.co/if7VqrZoFKBJt4lAAoy0/

```
  <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="right">

      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content layout-padding="">
        <md-tabs>
          <md-tab label="Tab #1"></md-tab>
          <md-tab label="Tab #2"></md-tab>
          <md-tab label="Tab #3"></md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
      </md-content>

    </md-sidenav>
```

I've duplicated 2 sidenavs: one uses the class`md-sidenav-left` and the other uses `md-sidenav-right`. The right one does not allow for the tabs or any content to be interacted with.

The example and my actual code are using 0.11.4 but I've also tested 1.0 and it has the same issue.

Has anyone run into this issue? The example on the Materials site works just fine but it does not use tabs. I'm thinking it's a `translate3d` css issue but can't confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out their css was trying to piggyback on `md-sidenav-left` instead of creating a new style.

Here is the fixed Plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/7L6GuUH036F2W9i7JPwl/

Here is the original SCSS from the build:

```
.md-sidenav-right {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  &.md-closed {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

`translate3d` and `left: 100%` turned out to be the issue. The reason why it exists though is to create the correct animation.

Here is the corrected SCSS:

```
.md-sidenav-right {
  left: inherit;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  &.md-closed {
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  } 
}
```